# The power button on my Galaxy Nexus stopped working

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, buttons

I got a galaxy nexus at Google IO, and randomly today the power button stopped working. I was on a call, used it to lock the screen after I got off, put it in my pocket, and when I got home the button wasn't working. The rest of the phone works if I plug it in to charge (waking up the screen), but the button doesn't respond. Short press doesn't lock/wake and long press doesn't bring the power menu up. What happened and how can I fix it?

I've tried pulling the battery and letting it sit for a few minutes without rebooting it, and it didn't help.

Comment: Can you start the phone after you've turned it off?

Comment: @onik: I can only turn it off by pulling the battery, and inserting the battery automatically turns it on. I spoke with Samsung support and set up an RMA. They said it seemed to be a hardware problem. I'll post that as an answer when it's completely resolved, but I see no reason why it shouldn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the phone is working normally except for the power button not responding, you most likely have a hardware issue. That is, the power button is probably physically broken.

In this case, you will need to return the phone to the manufacturer or the point of purchase for a repair or replacement.

Before returning the phone, copy off any personal data you wish to keep, and remove the battery, SD card, SIM card and any external case; do not ship those or any other accessories back along with the phone. You may get a replacement phone, and your data and accessories will not be transferred.

Comment: This is what I'm in the process of doing. When the RMA is approved and I get the replacement back (confirmation that they will repair this problem), I'll mark this accepted. Also as of today, rapidly pressing the button multiple times and/or pressing it very hard brings the screen on,  but it's not reliable.

Comment: Yep, sounds like the power button hardware has come loose. That happened to my original Motorola DROID.

Comment: Thanks, this was the right route to go. It was indeed a hardware defect, and Samsung was prompt in repairing it (covered under warranty).