# power button defect: how do I turn my device on

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note, power-on

Recently my power button stopped working, meaning that it does not accept *any* input. With Cyanogenmod, it was easy to add easily accessible buttons in the notification area to turn the screen off.

However I fear the time when the phone is turned off some time in the future (maybe through 0% battery level). How do I turn the device on?

I hesitate opening the device (which I've done before) because of this very same situation. I'm not sure if the button is repairable, so I'd very much like to have a backup plan to turn it back on (since for opening the device, the battery must be removed).

Comment: I don't have a real answer for you, but some related readings which might prove helpful: [How can I boot my Nexus S with a broken power button?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27643/16575) / [Power button stopped on my Nexus S](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/30455/16575) / [The power button on my Galaxy Nexus stopped working](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/26358/16575)

Answer (score 2):

If it's a hardware defect, I would suggest sending it to a service center for repair. You could plug it to a portable power bank so it lasts longer. But before you do that, you might want to back up your data to your PC or somewhere else first.

Comment: Is there another stackexchange platform more suitable?

Comment: Btw I actually think it's on topic related to Android. There might be some software solution mapping the home button to power up the device. Should be fairly simple, especially with CyanogenMod.

Comment: @stefan You're right. I removed my comment. So, what you're looking for is how to remap your power button.

Comment: Power button cannot be mapped as that is physical and the kernel has the input driver mapped to the pin used to activate the power itself... just saying :) A more appropriate answer is if its under warranty get it fixed by the service center :)

Answer (score 2):

"plug into charger or computer while u press power button + vol down + home when the os screen"

Should be without power button pressing because power button does not work.

But when this is followed it DID WORK! Thanks!

(exiting firmware menu boots the phone)

Worked with Galaxy Note 3.

Comment: Should work on almost any samsung device

Comment: Really this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

User1504... Was on the right track kinda. If you can remove your battery this solution worked for my s3 with a broken power button.

1. Remove battery or turn off device some how (can use adb I believe. If you need some help with that lmk) if completely dead let it charge for a bit (5% ish maybe more) then unplug it and continue
2. Insert battery if you removed it
3. Plug the phone into a charger
4. Immediately after plugging in phone hold down the Volume down button and home button.

It should ask you if you want to continue to download mode by pressing the Volume up button or to restart device by pressing the Volume down button.

You want to press the Volume down button to restart the device.

Hope this helps. The broken power button on my s3 happened to fix it self some how but before it did I removed it since it kept rebooting. Anyways this should work wish you the best.

Answer (score 0):

This worked on my phone. Take off the back to have quick access to the battery. Plug in the phone to charge it. When the green battery icon is showing the phone is charging, QUICKLY unplug the phone, remove the battery, then reinstall the battery. You must do it as fast as possible.

An odd thing, but it works.

Answer (score -2):

plug into charger or computer while u press power button + vol down + home when the os screen comes up is will ask you if you want to continue press vol or exit press vol down you press vol down to exit phone will boot up

Comment: But the problem is that power button doesn't work.